# ¿Cómo verificar qué elementos están en dos listas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo este problema, tengo dos listas con nombres de personas y **tengo que ver que personas se encuentran en ambas listas**:

```
clase_a = ["Andrés", "María", "Antonio", "Candido", "Javier", "Jose", "Manuel", "Gema", "Lola", "Carla"]
clase_b = ["Andrés", "Marta", "German", "Elena", "Jaime", "Jose", "Manuel", "Alfonso", "Victor", "Carla"]
```

Para ello utilicé lo que se llama **bucles anidados** y tras mucho intentarlo conseguí esta solución:

```
ambas_clases = []

for alumno_a in clase_a:
    for alumno_b in clase_b:
        if alumno_a == alumno_b:
            ambas_clases.append(alumno_a)
```

Aunque tengo la sensación de que es muy **ineficiente**, he estado intentando tratar de hacer otras cosas, pero lo único que he conseguido que funcione es el código anterior

Todo lo que he tenido han sido o listas con un resultado que no es el correcto, o `SyntaxError`.

Comment: he conseguido reducir 5 lineas de codigos a 3 palabras !!!!!! gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de darte la respuesta con **listas**, yo suelo usar la función de Python `set()`, `set` significa en español "conjunto" y en Python están implementados de la misma forma que son los conjuntos de elementos en matemáticas, por lo que puedes hacer la **intersección de dos conjuntos de elementos** o más, con el operador `&`:

```
clase_a = ["Andrés", "María", "Antonio", "Candido", "Javier", "Jose", "Manuel", "Gema", "Lola", "Carla"]
clase_b = ["Andrés", "Marta", "German", "Elena", "Jaime", "Jose", "Manuel", "Alfonso", "Victor", "Carla"]

set(clase_a) & set(clase_b)
```

**Salida:** `{'Andrés', 'Carla', 'Jose', 'Manuel'}`

Después si quieres puedes convertirlo a lista, con la función de Python `list()`

Como he dicho al principio, el `set()` en Python **representa un conjunto matemático**, por lo que tiene muchos más operadores para poder llevar a cabo multiples tipos de **operaciones entre conjuntos**:

- `|`: para la unión
- `-`: para la diferencia
- `^`: para la diferencia simétrica.
- `<=`: para saber si un conjunto `A` es un subconjunto de `Omega`

Y muchos más métodos que puedes ver en la [documentación oficial de Python](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/#set-operators)

### Con listas

En el caso de que quieras seguir con listas, el código con el que lo solucionas solo es necesaria un bucle `for` si utilizas la palabra reservada del lenguaje `in`. Con `in` chequeas si dicho elemento se encuentra en otro conjunto de elementos. Por lo que tu código quedaría así:

```
ambas_clases = []
for alumnno in clase_a:
    if alumno in clase_b: #Si alumno se encuentra en clase_b agregaló
        ambas_clases.append(alumno)
```

O con **list comprehension**, quedarías el mísmo código en una linea:

```
ambas_clases = [alumno for alumno in clase_a if alumno in clase_b]
```

En este caso todo comienza en el `for` , después va al `if` y si se cumple el condicional, devolvemos `alumno`. Al final tendremos todos los alumnos que se encuentran en ambos conjuntos en una lista.

### Bonus extra

Como se dijo al principio estas operaciones entre conjuntos de elementos, es mejor hacerlas con `set`, ya que **Python los tiene especificamente preparados para ello**, pudiendo ser bastante **más rápido** y te ahorras escribir muchas lineas de código. Cuando he hecho pruebas ha habido diferencias de **entre 10 y 100 veces más raṕido** (dependerá de las operaciones y la cantidad de datos).

Incluso en la solución que te he dado con listas, si lo dejas todo igual, y tan solo conviertes previamente `clase_b` a `set` conseguirás que la ejecución se realice en la mitad de tiempo.

Comment: Esto no quiere decir que siempre hay que usar **set**, o que sean mejor que las **listas**, solo quiere decir, que para este caso  específico es mejor. Pero ambos conjuntos de datos, son muy usados en Python

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda