# Python. Comparar elementos de conjuntos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que pedirle a dos usuarios sus intereses y guardarlos en conjuntos y finalmente comparar si esos dos usuarios tienen intereses comunes.

Este es mi código:

```
p1 = set()
numero_intereses_p1 = int(input("¿Cuántos intereses deseas introducir?"))
i = 1
while i <= numero_intereses_p1:
    intereses_p1 = input("Introduce el interés:")
    p1.add(intereses_p1)
    i = i + 1
#print(p1)

p2 = set()
numero_intereses_p2 = int(input("¿Cuántos intereses deseas introducir?"))
i = 1
while i <= numero_intereses_p2:
    intereses_p2 = input("Introduce el interés:")
    p2.add(intereses_p2)
    i = i + 1
#print(p2)

if intereses_p2 in intereses_p1:
    print(intereses_p2)
else:
    print("No hay intereses comunes")
```

Lo que ocurre es que me compara los intereses pero sólo me muestra el último interés común, es decir si el primer usuario introduce como intereses Fútbol, Pádel, Golf y el segundo usuario introduce Pádel, Golf, sólo me muestra Golf. En cambio si no hay ningún interés común muestra bien que no hay ningún interés común.

¿Alguien sabría decirme qué se me está escapando?
¡Gracias!

Comment: Debes recorrer la primera lista y comprobar si cada elemento está en la segunda

Comment: Respondí una pregunta similar aquí: [¿Cómo verificar que elementos estan en dos listas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/410825/c%c3%b3mo-verificar-que-elementos-estan-en-dos-listas/410827#410827) por si te es de ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) de `set`:

```py
intereses_comunes = intereses_p1.intersection(intereses_p2)
```

Como indica @abulafia en los comentarios, también puedes usar la sintaxis `&`

```py
intereses_comunes = intereses_p1 & intereses_p2
```

Comment: @ArianJs ¡Gracias! No conocía ese método ;-)

Comment: Python es nunca más tener que escribir `for ()`

Comment: @Janire cuando alguna vez pienses "esto es una acción frecuente", entonces vete a la documentación y mira a ver si no lo han implementado ya. Hablando de sets, las intersectiones y uniones, son frecuentes. Me alegro de haber ayudado

Comment: También se admite la sintaxis `intereses_p1 & intereses_p2` para hacer la intersección

Comment: @ArianJM busqué en la documentación y probé varias cosas que no me funcionaron. No busqué el método intersection porque no lo conocía y me lo has descubierto, así que gracias de nuevo!